# How to fetch GPS trace from web service based on OpenStreetMap

Tags: javascript, web-services, gps, openstreetmap, gpx

I'd like to get GPS all traces from [this](http://podgik.jgora.pl/jakuszyce/index.html) web service which is based on [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org).
 **Is it possible? How to do that?**

Comment: Did you try to contact the author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This service uses IMHO OSM just as basemap layer but the tracks itself don't rely on open data. Thus as @scai says you need to find an agreement with the pages operator.

If you analyse the website, you will see, that the tracklayer is embedded via an WMS. That means it comes prerendered to your browser and you can't extract the vector data easily.